# Using Tempdata is crashing my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm very new to ASP.NET and am attempting to pass an object between two controllers in a web application I'm making in Visual Studio 2015. The web application is using an ASP.Net 5 Preview Template Web application (if it helps, I think I'm using beta code 7 and I'm **not** building for DNX Core 5).

The problem I'm having is whenever I try to put *anything* into the TempData variable, the program seems to crash. For example, in a "Create" method I have:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Query query)
    {
        switch (query.QueryTypeID)
        {
            case 1:
                TempData["Test"] = "Test";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "EventResults");
            case 2:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

In that method, I attempt to add a simple test string under the key "test". When I run the application with that TempData statement in there, I receive an error message stating

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application >or request.
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpContext.get_Session()

I have tried going to the Web.config located in the wwwroot element of the project and adding a "sessionState" object into a "system.web" element, but this had no effect on the error.

Any help would be very much so appreciated as I've been looking for solutions for this everywhere. I'm hoping it's something stupid/blindingly obvious that I somehow missed.

Comment: Have you added the `Microsoft.AspNet.Session` nuget package and added the session middleware in the `Startup` class?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, Pheilberg. I have tried adding that Nuget package individually, and it caused a bunch of strange errors ("iApplicationBuilder is defined in a package that is not referenced" or something like that), but I am reading the answer you left and will try all of that. Thanks a lot for the suggestions and I'll mark it if it works!

Comment: If you can't get it to work, check out the [session sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/tree/dev/samples/SessionSample) in the [Session Github Repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/). If you still can't get it to work, post your `project.json` and `Startup.cs` code.

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly! I think the problem I had before was twofold: First, I wasn't installing the same version of nuget package that my code was running (My code was beta7 and I was downloading the latest. Like I said, this is all new to me... For other newbies who may see this, make sure the package you are going to download is the same beta version as all your dependencies in your project.json file!). Second, I didn't know I needed the caching package. Thanks a lot for helping me out! It is much appreciated!

Comment: Good that you sorted it out. I forgot to mention the package version part.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In order to use middleware, such as Session, Cache, etc in ASP.NET 5, you have to enable them explicitly.

Enabling session is done by adding the appropriate nuget package in your `project.json` file's dependencies section (make sure that the package version matches the versions of the other dependencies you have added):

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-*"
```

and the appropriate session (cache) storage package as well (like the example below; in memory):

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0-*"
```

and adding the middleware to dependency resolution in the `Startup.cs` Service configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCaching();
    services.AddSession(/* options go here */);
}
```

and adding the middleware to OWIN in the `Startup.cs` OWIN configuration:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSession();
    //...
```

Make sure that the `UseSession` comes *before* the MVC configuration.

Comment: Following is probably true, correct? For ASP.NET Core, in `congfigurationServices(...)` replace `services.AddCaching();` wirh `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();` Ref: [Installing and Configuration sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state#installing-and-configuring-session)

Comment: Apparently the session package is now called `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session`. It worked out-of-the-box without having to set up in-memory caching.

Comment: What are the options to put in the AddSession params?

Answer (score 7):

For Asp.Net Core, make sure `Asp.NetCore.Session` is added.
You can configure session in StartUp.cs  like below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

    {
        services.AddMvc();
         services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
        // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

Comment: When I try to add `Asp.NetCore.Session`, my project won't start anymore throwing the following error: `System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'ConfigureAppConfiguration' in type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.'`. Seems like I can't even add the nuget properly

Comment: @WouterVanherck it seems problem with package that you have added.remove package once ,clean solution and re-add nuget.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. However, removing packages is not an option in my case since something went terribly wrong and I can't build the project without them anymore

Comment: Before Installing package make sure download or install package according to your asp.net core framework. otherwise there will be issue,